# I trid this code for calendar and does not run

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

in "developer.android.com" I tried this code to make a calendar remind me at 03:30 pm with a toast message or notification but it does not work

MainActivity.java

```
package com.osman.calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 3:30 pm.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 20 minutes.
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

and AlarmReceiver.java

```
package com.osman.calendar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Time is up!!!!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Vibrate the mobile phone
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    }
}
```

and androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Have you added your broadcast receiver in the manifest?

`<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />`

Comment: Does not work how? Raises an Exception? Does not perform the operation? Please clarify.

Comment: @Joseph82 where I put this receiver

Comment: Inside the <application> tag in the Mainifest. It should be at the same level of <activity>